# Tableview custom cell button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I made a tableview with customcells. Cells include labels and a button. The question is, how can i detect the label's text when its button is pressed?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    // Initialization code
        primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        primaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
        primaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        secondaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        secondaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9];
        secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:btn];
        [self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:secondaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
    }

    return self;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This isn't that hard to do, but it will depend on how you set up the cell. Can you show us the code where you create the cell, labels and buttons?

Comment: i have also a reminder function i have to catch the cell content and set the eventcontroller for the calendar..

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is – addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Using you example, you have a UIButton, btn, and let's say you have an action in your custom cell called myAction. The code would look like this:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:myAction forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Because myAction is a method in your cell, you can easily access the label property. If you need to put your action in a different controller:

```
[btn addTarget:otherController action:myAction forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In this case you will have to keep a reference to your cell in the controller. Since you probably have more than one cell you could keep an NSMutableArray as a property and add your cells as you build your table.